# Where are array declared as pointers stored?

Tags: arrays, c

`char* str; fgets(str, 40, stdin);`

In this case for example, it should be in heap right?

Comment: heap memory is indicated by `malloc` or similar

Comment: There is no array in your code and no arrays are stored anywhere. Which is why the code is broken.

Comment: You should not think of a pointer as being the thing it points to. I have seen this multiple times on Stack Overflow recently, such as somebody writing of “the memory of a pointer being freed” when referring to the memory that the pointer points to rather than the memory that holds the pointer value. A pointer is **just** an address of something else. It is not the something else, it is not tied to the something else, it is not freed when the something else is freed, and the something else is not freed when the pointer is freed…

Comment: … As a simple analogy, consider an `int x` that I use as a subscript into an array `char A[1024]`. If `x` is 534, meaning I use it to refer to `A[534]`, then `x` is not that `char`, `x` can change to refer to some other element of the array, `x` and `A[534]` have different memories to hold their values, and freeing one does not free the other. A pointer is the same as this `int`, except it uses a direct memory address (in the C model of computing) rather than a subscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the code invokes undefined behavior because there is no allocated memory extent that contains at least 40 bytes where you are going to read a string.

As for this declaration

```
char* str;
```

then if it appears in a function then it has the automatic storage duration and the pointer `str` has an indeterminate value.

If this declaration appears in a file scope then the pointer has the static storage duration and is initialized as a null pointer.

You could for example write

```
char s[40];
char* str = s; 
fgets(str, 40, stdin);
```

In this case the pointer `str` points to the first character of the array `s`.

Or

```
char* str = malloc( sizeof( char[40] ) ); 
fgets(str, 40, stdin);
```

In this case the pointer `str` points to the dynamically allocated array of 40 characters in the heap.

That is when you declare a pointer the compiler does not allocate at the same time an array to which the pointer will point. You should explicitly initialize or assign a pointer to the address of an already allocated array if you are going tp use the pointer with an array.

In C there are four kinds of storage durations: static, thread, automatic and allocated. Usually programmers use the term stack when they mean the automatic storage duration and the term heap when they mean the allocated storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

This code will have undefined behavior `(most probably cause Segmentation Fault)`.

You have to allocate memory for `char *str`, using some dynamic memory allocation methods like

- malloc()
- calloc()

Then it will be stored in **heap**.

So modified code should be :-

```
char* str;
str = (char *)malloc(40 * sizeof(char));
fgets(str, 40, stdin);
```

Here the **str** is stored inside **heap**.

Comment: You don’t need to and (by wide consensus) *should not* cast `void` pointers in C. Furthermore, you shouldn’t separate declaration and initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no array in your code. There’s only an unassigned pointer. You cannot use this pointer, you first need to assign a value to it. That value *can* be (the first element of) an array, but you need to create that array yourself. Your current code doesn’t do this, and consequently doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to cause a *Segmentation Fault*. Your program tries to read in characters from stdin to the char* str. In this case, str is a *loose pointer*. It doesn't point to any array in the memory, it just has some random value in it. (most likely 0). The important thing is that wherever it is pointing - you don't have that memory allocated. When you call fgets(), your program will write characters in the memory location where str is pointing to. But your program doesn't "own" the memory where str is pointing to, so the operating system will terminate you program with a *Segmentation fault*.

Comment: I’ve never heard the term “loose pointer”. It’s usually known as a “dangling pointer”, but this is also not entirely correct. `str` isn’t dangling, it’s unassigned (unless it’s declared at file scope). Dangling pointer, by contrast, have a defined value which doesn’t point to a valid memory location.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, I know str is unassigned. What I'm trying to tell here is that str is pointing to some random location in memory, so it's "dangling" somewhere in the RAM. I know it's not 100% technically correct to a pro C coder, but as I can see the person who asked this question is a beginner in the C programming language. I wanted to explain it as simply as possible "the way how C and computers work" and not put in new concepts like unassigned.

Comment: Re “This is going to cause a Segmentation Fault”: This **may** cause a segmentation fault. It might not. And telling students it will could lead them to believe that, if there is no segmentation fault in a particular program, they are not failing to initialize some pointer or overrun some buffer—they may overlook the cause of a bug. So it is important that students know that errors like this may or may not cause a fault.

Comment: Re “In this case, str is a loose pointer”: That is not at all a common term, certainly not something deserving of the italics that mark a formal term. The few uses of it (as a computer science term, rather than an unrestrained dog of the English Pointer breed, I find in Google are more in reference to a pointer to memory that has been freed. That is, it is not an uninitialized pointer object but rather a previously assigned pointer that has been disconnected (made loose) by freeing the memory it pointed to. Even that is more commonly called a “dangling pointer.”

Comment: Re “it just has some random value in it. (most likely 0)”: The value is not random (except in rare circumstances where actual random data has been used somewhere in the program) and is not most likely zero except in simple programs of the kind often posted on Stack Overflow that have no prior use of the stack before these errors. Formally, the value is *indeterminate* per the C standard, meaning not only is its value not determined but that the object may act as if it does not hold the same value from time to time.

Comment: Re “The important thing is that wherever it is pointing - you don't have that memory allocated”: Well, they could, and that could be worse. Using an uninitialized pointer might happen to pick up some valid address left on the stack, and then using it could overwrite memory needed for something else, resulting in a hard-to-diagnose failure occurring in the program later.